# How to say "don't take it to heart" in Italian?

Tags: word-choice, single-words, foreign-words

How do you say "don't take it to heart" in Italian? I think it could be translated as "fregatene". Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*fregatene* would fit more either *don't care* or even *don't give a ....* because it's a little harsh.

> How do you say "don't take it to heart" in Italian?

You could say:

- Non prendertela (closest non-literal translation);
- Lascia perdere (*let go*), and
- Non importa (*it doesn't matter*)

Answer (score 6):

Well, we say *[non prendertela a cuore](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/C/cuore.shtml#30)*

> **prendere a cuore**
>
> Interessarsi attivamente di qualcosa, curarsene in modo fattivo.

*Fregatene* is in my opinion a bit too colloquial and slightly rude compared to the English expression.

Comment: It's the second time I get reputation for pointing out that the obvious translation is correct. I cannot but feel that I'm stealing :)

Comment: You are not stealing anything. Rather, why this is not the accepted answer?